# Odoo:- How to inherit and replace a inherited template in website_sale?

Tags: xml, inheritance, odoo

Here i want inherit and replace a inherited template in a separate folder, i want inherit the below code. and its located in

> addons/website_sale/views/templates.xml

```
<template id="products_add_to_cart" inherit_id="website_sale.products_item" active="False" customize_show="True" name="Add to Cart">
  <xpath expr="//div[@class='product_price']" position="inside">
    <input name="product_id" t-att-value="product.product_variant_ids[0].id" type="hidden"/>
    <t t-if="len(product.product_variant_ids) == 1">
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs fa fa-shopping-cart a-submit"/>
    </t>
    <t t-if="len(product.product_variant_ids) &gt; 1">
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs fa fa-shopping-cart" t-att-href="keep('/shop/product/%s' % slug(product), page=(pager['page']['num'] if pager['page']['num']>1 else None))"/>
    </t>
  </xpath>
</template>
```

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use like.

```
<template id="products_add_to_cart" inherit_id="website_sale.products_add_to_cart">
 write ur xpath and replace element or tag  
</template>
```